# TOC points to last page of part

Tags: table-of-contents, classicthesis

I'm working in the classic-thesis template on my thesis.

I like to devote a part-only piece of the thesis to the hypothesis, i.e. a part which does not contain chapters. This part is 3 pages long.

Everything seems to work, but the entry for the part in the TOC refers to the last instead of the first page of the TOC.
Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Many thanks,
Merijn

Below a minimal outline of how the part looks like. I cut away the text for legibility, but the thing is overall 3 pages long:

```
%PART THESIS HYPOTHESIS
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\ctparttext{
\thispagestyle{plain}
here is one page of text..

\pagebreak
\thispagestyle{plain}
here is text, and a figure.

\pagebreak
\thispagestyle{plain}

here is one new page of text..
}
\part{Thesis Hypothesis: blablabla ...}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

EDIT:
I think I got closer to the problem. I include a part containing 3-pages.
The middle page contains a graph.

The page number stated in the TOC is the LAST page of the part. If one clicks on the page number in the toc, one jumbs to the figure, which is in the second page of the part. When I remove the figure, the entry correctly points to the top of the first page, and clicking on it one also jumbs to correct point. Clearly, adding a figure to the part screws up the TOC. 
I checked, the `\pagebreak` insertions in the part seem not to be the cause of the problem.

Does anyone knows how to solve this? 
To reproduce the problem: 
-one needs to load the latest `classicthesis` package 
-Comment out `cftpagenumbersoff{part}` in `classicthesis.sty`
-In the `classicthesis` file add the `\part` I put below. Apparently I cannot attach my latex file..

This reproduces the problem. If one removes the equation and figure, the problem is solved again.

```
\ctparttext{

\thispagestyle{plain}
Investigating the hypothesis on the realisation of gluon saturation is of paramount importance for our fundamental understanding of Nature. Over 99\% of the mass of the visible matter in our universe is effectively generated by QCD, and saturation may elegantly account for this. For the latter, the large number of small-$x$ gluons are envisaged as a classical background field. Due to this background field the high-$x$ partons become inert. Furthermore, gluon saturation is expected to tame the exponential growth of the gluon pdf, and thus prevent the occurrence of a unitarity violation in the QCD description of hadronic interactions. Besides, gluon saturation is an important theoretical ingredient for formulating predictions on the initial state of heavy ion collisions, which constitute a core research program at the LHC. Also, cosmic-ray studies may directly benefit from improved modelling of the low-x content of hadrons (as was shown for the ultra-forward LHCf measurement in Fig.~\ref{fig:LHCComparisonrcBK}). Precision measurements of the Brout-Englert-Higgs boson may furthermore indirectly benefit from saturation studies, since the latter may constrain the uncertainty on the gluon pdf. Since gluon fusion is the dominant production mechanism of the scalar boson at the LHC, an improvement in the gluon pdf uncertainty would certainly not be of modest importance. 

These core arguments elucidate why, since non-linear parton evolution was hypothesised over two decades ago~\cite{DGLAP:Gribov}, saturation has been at the focal point of the theoretical and experimental community. So far, numerous papers have been presented on the topic. Models incorporating saturation have been confronted with a wealth of data, spanning nearly three decades of particle physics experiments. A central incentive for the recent proton-lead collisions at $\sqrt{s_{\mathrm{NN}}}=$5 and 8 TeV at the LHC is the search for signals of gluon saturation. Ambitions for the future include the foreseen construction of an electron-ion collider; a pivotal argument for this endeavour is a precision measurement of saturation in a heavy ion~\cite{EIC,LHeC}.

\pagebreak
\thispagestyle{plain}

Optimal sensitivity to probe gluon saturation may be achieved by measuring low-pt jets in the forward direction. This statement can be motivated straightforwardly, since in a hard-parton interaction the $x$-value of the parton can, to leading order, be reconstructed from the kinematical properties of the resulting jet via:
\begin{equation}
x=\frac{p_{t} e^{-|\eta|}}{\sqrt{s}}.
\end{equation}
We succinctly derive the relation in appendix~\ref{Appendix:Kinematics} for completeness. 

Concluding, forward low-pt jets probe the hadron at low-$x$, where the effects of saturation are strongest.
In Fig.~\ref{fig:AcceptanceLHCexperiments} (left) we depict the acceptances of the large LHC experiments, adapted to 5TeV proton-lead collisions with the proton boosted in the negative direction; the acceptances are depicted in the proton-nucleon centre-of-mass system. The plot is complemented with the existing HERA measurements, and parameterisations of the saturation scale in a proton and lead ion are overlaid.
\thispagestyle{plain}%important to remove an undesired header

\begin{figure}[bth]
\begin{center}
%\includegraphics[width=.42\linewidth]{Graphics/PartHypothesis/LHC_CASTOR_QCDAcceptance_pA_IncKS.pdf} 
%\includegraphics[width=.56\linewidth]{Graphics/PartHypothesis/AllModelsOnly.pdf}

\caption{Left: the acceptances of the large LHC experiments. These have been adjusted to the centre-of-mass system of a 5TeV proton-lead collision, with the proton towards CASTOR. The kinematic regime of the HERA measurements is overlaid. The collinearly improved proton saturation scale has been parameterised as $Q_{s}(x=)ce^{\lambda/x}$. We fixed $\lambda$ to 0.3~\cite{VirtualityEvoinHighDensityArticle}. Given the slope parameter, we adjusted $Q_{s}^{2}(p)$ to 0.36 at $x=0.01$~\cite{HeraFitAAMS}. The nuclear saturation scale $Q_{s}^{2}(p)$ is enhanced with a factor $A^{1/3}=5.9$ w.r.t.\,the proton saturation scale. The parameterisation of the KS saturation scales were obtained in a private communication. Right: predictions for the single-inclusive jet energy spectrum in CASTOR based on the AAMQS and KS analyses. MV refers to the McLerran-Venugopalan model, '01 to the second parameterisation from table 1 of~\cite{LHCComparisonAAMQS}, while '19 refers to the third parameterisation}
\label{fig:AcceptanceLHCexperiments}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

The CMS experiment at the LHC has been equipped with the CASTOR calorimeter, which extends the range in which jets can be measured (in the lab frame) to $-6.6<\eta<-5.2$ (CASTOR is only installed at one side of the CMS experiment). This calorimeter can measure very low pt jets, the minimal pt values presented in this analysis correspond to ${\approx}3$GeV.

\pagebreak
\thispagestyle{plain}

A study of jets in CASTOR in proton-lead collisions at the unrivalled centre-of-mass energies of the LHC thus possesses unique sensitivity to non-linear evolution effects. 
Evidently, such an analysis would overcome the adversities that obscured the conclusions in the HERA and RHIC analyses. The nuclear saturation scale for $\sqrt{s}=5TeV$ p+Pb collisions in the CASTOR acceptance is expected to be around $10GeV$; this is well above the pertubative limit $\Lambda_{QCD}^{2}$. Furthermore, a jet with a pt of 3GeV may be caused by a \textit{hard} parton with an $x$-value of ${\approx}0.25$. Thus, the fragmentation functions are not evaluated at the kinematic limit $x\rightarrow1$.

In Fig.~\ref{fig:AcceptanceLHCexperiments} (right) we present predictions for the single-inclusive jet-energy spectrum \footnote{The single inclusive jet spectrum can easily be related to the single inclusive particle spectrum by clustering the particles with a jet algorithm} in the CASTOR acceptance n 5TeV proton-lead collisions, based on the KS and AAMQS fits to HERA e+p data. It can be observed that the KS and MRW predictions for linear and non-linear parton evolution lead to very distinct solutions, which differ more than an order of magnitude at low jet energies. The AAMQS fits give very similar results for the the g'01 and g'19 parameterisation, while the MV model has a different slope.
Concluding, the CASTOR single-inclusive jet spectrum constitutes indeed a very powerful observable to scrutinise hypotheses on saturation.

Given all the advantages and benefits of an analysis of jets in CASTOR in proton-lead collisions, such a study is on the other hand certainly not free of complications and obstacles. The CASTOR calorimeter was originally not designed to measure jets, which induces various afflictions (which will be extensively reviewed). In spite of various endeavours to study CASTOR jets in p+p collisions, this is the first CASTOR jet analysis that is in the process of submission to a journal. Given the experimental state-of-the-art, this thesis therefore targets two objectives: proving the experimental validity of CASTOR jets, and ultimately exploiting these to probe saturation. 
}
\part{Thesis Hypothesis: an unprecedented experimental search for signals of saturation}%\label{Part:saturation}%tried to assign a label, didn't solve it.
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%ADDITION PART MERIJN ENDS
```

Comment: Please take a look on https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Comment: First of all, this is not how you're supposed to use \ctparttext. For the rest, I'm not sure what exactly you want.

Comment: Dear flav and Philip, many thanks for the replies.
I just checked out a fresh version of the classicthesis package to provide a minimal working example.
To my suprise, in the latest classicthesis package the \part pieces do appear in the TOC, but without a page number (which would circumvent the problem).

I'll try to get things sorted in this new distribution first, if doesn't work I'll come back.
Sorry on this, got the package only few months ago, didn't expect this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the issue with a `\part` piece consisting of multiple pages in the following way: The `pagestyle{clean}` is to avoid the title of the last previous chapter to be printed above the page. I needed `\pagebreak` still in suitable places, perhaps there is a better way around.

In the classic-thesis this worked for me, the entry in the TOC points to the correct page and if one clicks it one is pointed to the title of the part (instead of an equation or picture in the text). Many thanks again for the comments!

```
{
\let\newpage\relax
\makeatletter
 \titlespacing*{\part}
    {\z@}
    {\z@}
    {\z@}
\makeatother
\part{Here give the title of the part}
}

\thispagestyle{plain}

first of page text..

\pagebreak
\thispagestyle{plain}

Second page of text...

%before a new \part starts apply:

\cleardoublepage
```